# Do Go generics allow for a LINQ to Objects equivalent?

Tags: linq, go, generics

With the [addition of generics in Go 1.18](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18#generics), would it now be possible to come up with an equivalent of C#'s [LINQ to Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects)?

Or are Go's generics lacking something in principle, compared to C# generics, that will make that difficult or impossible?

For example, the first of the original [101 LINQ samples](https://github.com/dotnet/try-samples/blob/main/101-linq-samples/src/Restrictions.cs#L16-L26) ("LowNumbers") could now be implemented in Go with generics roughly like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type collection[T comparable] []T

func (input collection[T]) where(pred func(T) bool) collection[T] {
    result := collection[T]{}
    for _, j := range input {
        if pred(j) {
            result = append(result, j)
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    numbers := collection[int]{5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0}
    lowNums := numbers.where(func(i int) bool { return i < 5 })
    fmt.Println("Numbers < 5:")
    fmt.Println(lowNums)
}
```

Comment: I only used LINQ a tiny bit back in .net 3.5, but I've tried a few ORM packages in Go. Many are "objects first" and build your database from your code. A popular package is GORM, though there are some "lighter weight" ones like sqlx. My personal favorite is a different take on it: "database first". The excellent SQLBoiler package will generate structs and a lot of useful query builder methods from the actual schema of your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm not a C# expert)

A conspicuous difference between Go's parametric polymorphism and the implementation of generics in C# or Java is that Go (still) has no syntax for co-/contra-variance over type parameters.

For example in C# you can have code that implements `IComparer<T>` and pass derived container classes; or in Java the typical `Predicate<? super T>` in the stream API. In Go, types must match exactly, and instantiating a generic type with different type parameters yields different named types that just can't be assigned to each other. See also: [Why does Go not allow assigning one generic to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71399641/why-does-go-not-allow-assigning-one-generic-to-another/)

Also Go is not OO, so there's no concept of inheritance. You may have types that implement interfaces, and even parametrized interfaces. A contrived example:

```
type Equaler[T any] interface {
    Equals(T) bool
}

type Vector []int32

func (v Vector) Equals(other Vector) bool {
    // some logic
}
```

So with this code, `Vector` implements **a specific instance** of `Equaler` which is `Equaler[Vector]`. To be clear, the following var declaration compiles:

```
var _ Equaler[Vector] = Vector{}
```

So with this, you can write functions that are generic in `T` and use `T` to instantiate `Equaler`, and you will be able to pass anything that does implement that specific instance of `Equaler`:

```
func Remove[E Equaler[T], T any](es []E, v T) []E {
    for i, e := range es {
        if e.Equals(v) {
            return append(es[:i], es[i+1:]...)
        }
    }
    return es
}
```

And you can call this function with any `T`, and therefore with any `T` that has an `Equals(T)` method:

```
// some other random type that implements Equaler[T]
type MyString string

// implements Equaler[string]
func (s MyString) Equals(other string) bool {
    return strings.Split(string(s), "-")[0] == other
}

func main() {
    vecs := []Vector{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8}}
    fmt.Println(Remove(vecs, Vector{6, 7})) 
    // prints [[1 2] [3 4 5] [8]]

    strs := []MyString{"foo-bar", "hello-world", "bar-baz"}
    fmt.Println(Remove(strs, "hello"))
    // prints [foo-bar bar-baz]
}
```

The only problem is that only defined types can have methods, so this approach already excludes all composite non-named types.

However, to a partial rescue, Go has higher-order functions, so writing a stream-like API with that and non-named types is not impossible, e.g.:

```
func Where[C ~[]T, T any](collection C, predicate func(T) bool) (out C) {
    for _, v := range collection {
        if predicate(v) {
            out = append(out, v)
        }
    }
    return 
}

func main() {
    // vecs declared earlier
    filtered := Where(vecs, func(v Vector) bool { return v[0] == 3})
    fmt.Printf("%T %v", filtered, filtered)
    // prints []main.Vector [[3 4 5]]
}
```

In particular here you use a named type parameter `C ~[]T` instead of just defining `collection []T` so that you can use it with *both* named and non-named types.

Code available in the playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/mCM2TJ9qb3F

(Choosing the parametrized interfaces vs. higher-order functions probably depends on, among others, if you want to chain methods, but method chaining in Go isn't very common to begin with.)

**Conclusion**: whether that is enough to mimic LINQ- or Stream-like APIs, and/or enable large generic libraries, only practice will tell. The existing facilities are pretty powerful, and could become even more so in Go 1.19 after the language designers gain additional experience with real-world usage of generics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very detailed answer! Re method chaining - I understand it's not common in Go, more out of curiosity: how could a C# style chain `vecs.Where(...).Select(...).OrderBy(...)` work? I imagine the higher order functions need to be methods (like in my example), so that the next part of the chain can operate on the result of the previous one? But unlike functions, methods can't have their own type parameters, so you can't e.g. do `Select<TSource,TResult>` [like in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0).

Comment: @Max yup, a chain must be a series of methods. it is indeed used some times, but I rarely saw long chains in the wild. I use them in unit tests to construct mocks. One reason might be that even though in Go code you don't see semicolons, they are still statement terminators and the compiler adds them automatically. So to have multi-line chaining, you must add the selector dot `.` at the end of the line instead of the beginning, so the compiler knows to not insert a `;`. So the code then doesn't look very nice, esp if you're familiar w/ other forms of functional programming

Comment: About additional type parameters in methods, you're right that single methods can't have extra type params. All of them must be defined on the type, so that would be `type Vector[T, R any] []int32`, and methods with receiver `func (v Vector[T,R]) foo() {}`. A method may not need all type params, in which case you signal that with underscore `func (v Vector[T,_]) foo(t T) bool {}` or `func (v Vector[_,R]) foo() R {}`

Comment: Go methods just have different semantics from functions since one of their main purposes is to implement type constraints, and higher order functions *are inherently functions*. Imo, the best solution for go would be to just add a pipeline operator similar to the one in Elixir if people just want a clean chaining syntax, instead of modifying the type system to enable HOFs-as-methods. Personally I would suggest intermediate variables

Answer (score 8):

Yes and no.

You can *almost* get there using a chained APIs.
This works for many of the standard LINQ methods, such as `Skip`, `Take`, `Where`, `First`, `Last` etc.

What doesn't work, is when you need to switch to another generic type within a flow/stream.

Go Generics does not allow *methods* to have other type argument than the interface/struct for which they are defined.
e.g. you cannot have a struct `Foo[T any]` that then has a method `Bar[O any]`
This is needed for methods like `Select` where you have one type for the input and another type for the output.

However, if you don't use chaining and just go for plain functions. then you can get pretty close functionality-wise.

I've done that here: https://github.com/asynkron/gofun

This is a fully lazy enumerable implementation by simulating co-routines.

What doesn't work here is functions like `Zip` which needs to enumerate two enumerables at the same time. (although there are ways to hack that. but nothing pretty)

Answer (score 1):

Go generics does not support generic method at the time. But you can write generic functions.

```golang
// Filter selects items that f() returns true
func Filter[Src any](l []Src, f func(Src) bool) (result []Src) {
    result = make([]Src, 0, len(l)/2)
    for _, x := range l {
        if f(x) {
            result = append(result, x)
        }
    }
    return
}

func ExampleFilter() {
    lst := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    isEven := func(n int) bool { return n%2 == 0 } // expected filtered array of even numbers

    evens := Filter(lst, isEven)
    fmt.Println(evens)
    // Output: [2 4 6]
}
```

You can get Filter() and many other useful tool functions at my repository: https://github.com/szmcdull/glinq