# Go generics: why doesn't the switch case *A[any] match *A[int]

Tags: go, generics

Just started learning generics. I'm making a command processor and I honestly don't know how to word this so I'm just going to show an example problem:

```golang
var ErrInvalidCommand = errors.New("invalid command")

type TransactionalFn[T any] func(ctx context.Context, db T) error

func NewTransactionalCommand[T any](fn TransactionalFn[T]) *TransactionalCommand[T] {
    return &TransactionalCommand[T]{
        fn: fn,
    }
}

type TransactionalCommand[T any] struct {
    fn TransactionalFn[T]
}

func (cmd *TransactionalCommand[T]) StartTransaction() error {
    return nil
}

func (cmd *TransactionalCommand[T]) Commit() error {
    return nil
}

func (cmd *TransactionalCommand[T]) Rollback() error {
    return nil
}

type CMD interface{}

type CommandManager struct{}

func (m *CommandManager) Handle(ctx context.Context, cmd CMD) error {
    switch t := cmd.(type) {
    case *TransactionalCommand[any]:
        return m.handleTransactionalCommand(ctx, t)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", cmd)
        return ErrInvalidCommand
    }
}

func (m *CommandManager) handleTransactionalCommand(ctx context.Context, cmd *TransactionalCommand[any]) error {
    if err := cmd.StartTransaction(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := cmd.fn(ctx, nil); err != nil {
        if err := cmd.Rollback(); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    if err := cmd.Commit(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

// tests
type db struct{}

func (*db) Do() {
    fmt.Println("doing stuff")
}

func TestCMD(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    fn := func(ctx context.Context, db *db) error {
        fmt.Println("test cmd")
        db.Do()
        return nil
    }
    tFn := bus.NewTransactionalCommand(fn)

    mng := &bus.CommandManager{}
    err := mng.Handle(ctx, tFn)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

`mng.handle` returns `ErrInvalidCommand` so the test fails because `cmd` is `*TransactionalCommand[*db]` and not `*TransactionalCommand[any]`

Let me give another, more abstract example:

```golang
type A[T any] struct{}

func (*A[T]) DoA() { fmt.Println("do A") }

type B[T any] struct{}

func (*B[T]) DoB() { fmt.Println("do B") }

func Handle(s interface{}) {
    switch x := s.(type) {
    case *A[any]:
        x.DoA()
    case *B[any]:
        x.DoB()
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", s)
    }
}



func TestFuncSwitch(t *testing.T) {
    i := &A[int]{}

    Handle(i) // expected to print "do A"
}
```

Why doesn't this switch statement case `*A[any]` match `*A[int]`?
How to make `CommandManager.Handle(...)` accept generic Commands?

Comment: About manipulating `T` directly in a type switch: [How to assign or return generic T that is constrained by union?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047848/how-to-assign-or-return-generic-t-that-is-constrained-by-union)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*A[any]` does not match `*A[int]` because `any` is a static type, not a wildcard. Therefore instantiating a generic struct with different types [yields different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71399641/why-does-go-not-allow-assigning-one-generic-to-another).

In order to correctly match a generic struct in a type switch, you must instantiate it with a type parameter:

```
func Handle[T any](s interface{}) {
    switch x := s.(type) {
    case *A[T]:
        x.DoA()
    case *B[T]:
        x.DoB()
    default:
        panic("no match")
    }
}
```

Though in absence of other function arguments to infer `T`, you will have to call `Handle` with explicit instantiation. `T` won't be inferred from the struct alone.

```
func main() {
    i := &A[int]{}
    Handle[int](i) // expected to print "do A"
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/2e5E9LSWPmk

---

However when `Handle` is actually a method, as in your database code, this has the drawback of choosing the type parameter when instantiating the receiver.

In order to improve the code here you can make `Handle` a top-level function:

```
func Handle[T any](ctx context.Context, cmd CMD) error {
    switch t := cmd.(type) {
    case *TransactionalCommand[T]:
        return handleTransactionalCommand(ctx, t)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", cmd)
        return ErrInvalidCommand
    }
}
```

Then you have the problem of how to supply the argument `db T` to the command function. For this, you might:

- simply pass an additional `*db` argument to `Handle` and `handleTransactionalCommand`, which also helps with type parameter inference. Call as `Handle(ctx, &db{}, tFn)`. Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/6WESb86KN5D
- pass an instance of `CommandManager` (like solution above but `*db` is wrapped). Much more verbose, as it requires explicit instantiation everywhere. Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/SpXczsUM5aW
- use a parametrized interface instead (like below). So you don't even have to type-switch. Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/EgULEIL6AV5

```
type CMD[T any] interface {
    Exec(ctx context.Context, db T) error
}
```

Comment: From what you've written I assume that the answer is it can't be done? Since the end result can't be `mng := &bus.CommandManager{}` and `mng.Handle(ctx, tFn)` because you need to defined the type of the command manager and therefore can't have it `generic` enough to apply to any command type.

Comment: @CodeBreaker it can be done like you say, as shown in the [second playground](https://go.dev/play/p/SpXczsUM5aW), but it requires adding the type parameter on `CommandManager`, which is much more verbose. Personally, I prefer option 1 and 3

Answer (score 14):

**Why does the generic type switch fail to compile?**

- This is in fact the result of an intentional decision of the Go team. It turned out that allowing type switches on parametrized types can cause confusion
- > In an earlier version of this design, we permitted using type assertions and type switches on variables whose type was a type parameter, or whose type was based on a type parameter. We removed this facility because it is always possible to convert a value of any type to the empty interface type, and then use a type assertion or type switch on that. Also, it was sometimes confusing that in a constraint with a type set that uses approximation elements, a type assertion or type switch would use the actual type argument, not the underlying type of the type argument (the difference is explained in the section on identifying the matched predeclared type)

  From the [Type Parameters Proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#why-not-permit-type-assertions-on-values-whose-type-is-a-type-parameter)

Let me turn the emphasized statement into code. If the type constraint uses type approximation (note the tildes)...

`func PrintStringOrInt[T ~string | ~int](v T)`

...and if there also was a custom type with `int` as the underlying type...

`type Seconds int`

...and if `PrintOrString()` is called with a `Seconds` parameter...

`PrintStringOrInt(Seconds(42))`

...then the `switch` block would not enter the `int case` but go right into the `default case`, because `Seconds` is not an `int`. Developers might expect that `case int:` matches the type `Seconds` as well.

To allow a `case` statement to match both `Seconds` and `int` would require a new syntax, like, for example,

`case ~int:`

As of this writing, the discussion is still open, and maybe it will result in an entirely new option for switching on a type parameter (such as, `switch type T`).

More details, please refer to [proposal: spec: generics: type switch on parametric types](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45380)

---

**Trick: convert the type into 'any'**

Luckily, we do not need to wait for this proposal to get implemented in a future release. There is a super simple workaround available right now.

Instead of switching on `v.(type)`, switch on `any(v).(type)`.

```
switch any(v).(type) {
    ...
```

This trick converts `v` into an empty `interface{}` (a.k.a. `any`), for which the `switch` happily does the type matching.

---

Source: [A tip and a trick when working with generics](https://appliedgo.com/blog/a-tip-and-a-trick-when-working-with-generics)

Comment: this answer, and the solution `switch any(v).type`, is completely unrelated to the OP's problem. The OP isn't trying to switch on a `~` type, they are switching on a struct with a type parameter