# How to determine exact type of generic type in golang? Any type specialization?

Tags: go, generics, types, interface

I am working with Go generics and trying to implement encoding and decoding functions for a custom type `Opt[T ID]`. The `ID` interface is defined to include either an `Integer` or a `string`:

```golang
type Integer interface {
    ~int | ~int8 | ~int16 | ~int32 | ~int64 | ~uint | ~uint8 | ~uint16 | ~uint32 | ~uint64 | ~uintptr
}

type ID interface {
    Integer | ~string
}

type Opt[T ID] struct {
    Val T
}
```

I have successfully implemented the encoding function, `Enc`, which takes an `Opt[T ID]` and returns an `Opt[string]` containing the base64-encoded representation of the input value (not sure it's the best practice):

```golang
func Enc[T ID](opt Opt[T]) Opt[string] {
    result := Opt[string]{}
    strVal := fmt.Sprintf("%v", opt.Val)
    result.Val = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(strVal))
    return result
}
```

However, I am struggling with the decoding function, `Dec`, which should take an `Opt[string]` and return an `Opt[T ID]` containing the decoded value. I tried using a type `switch` and type assertion, but I cannot find a solution that compiles without errors.

How can I implement the `Dec` function to handle both `int` and `string` (including equivalent types) values?

Here's the code I have so far:

```golang
func Dec[T ID](opt Opt[string]) Opt[T] {
    result := Opt[T]{}

    data, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(opt.Val)
    strVal := string(data)
    var t T
    switch any(t).(type) { 
    case int:
        intVal, _ := strconv.Atoi(strVal)
        result.Val = intVal // error: cannot use intVal (variable of type int) as T value in assignment
    case string:
        result.Val = strVal // error: cannot use strVal (variable of type string) as T value in assignment
    }
    return result
}
```

I used the trick with `any` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72024835/go-generics-why-doesnt-the-switch-case-aany-match-aint)

Playground https://go.dev/play/p/COZqzl9g001

In C++ it's very easy to write specialization for any type, but Go doesn't seem to have it.

Is there any more or less elegant workaround?

Comment: You could use pointer indirection to set the result: https://go.dev/play/p/FCgW8VAlQve

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, but you added another `switch case`. Is there a way to do it without extending `Dec` with custom types?

Comment: I have added another case because your example instantiates the generic type with `MyInt` as the type argument, therefore you need to check against that type in the type switch. `MyInt` is _not_ `int`. They are different types. `case int:` will _never_ be selected if the argument is of type `MyInt`.